# why does instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier need to use "as!"

Tags: ios, swift

```
let someVC  = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("something") as! SomethingViewController
```

why do we need to use "as! DataEntryViewController"

it works when I take it out using xcode 7.3.1

Comment: If it works without it then you don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "works".

Yes, you can instantiate a view controller without caring which subclass of `UIViewController` it is. And the object you get back from that method will be a view controller, so it's safe to do things with it that can be done to all view controllers: present it modally, push it onto a navigation controller, add it to a tab controller, etc.

However, if you're going to do something with it that's specific to your view controller class -- like if `SomethingViewController` defines a property that lets you choose which `Something` it displays, and you want to assign to that property -- you need to do two things:

1. Test at runtime that the object you got back from `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is the class you expect it to be. (Because depending on the identifier you pass it could be some other class, or nothing at all if that identifier isn't in the storyboard.)
2. Let the compiler know that the variable you've assigned that object to is typed for that class, so that the compiler will let you access properties and call methods of that class.

Assignment with an `as?` or `as!` cast does both of those things in one step. (Whether to use `as?` or `as!` just depends on how much you trust yourself to make sure your storyboard identifiers are what they claim to be, and how you want to handle failure of such assumptions.)

---

In fact, even if you're not using properties or methods specific to that view controller class, that `as!` cast adds a runtime check that your view controller class is what you expect it to be. So the fact that nothing breaks when you take the cast out isn't a sign that the cast is superfluous — it's a sign that whatever breakage the cast was checking for is not currently happening.

That is, the line you quoted would lead to a crash if somebody changed your storyboard so that the identifier "something" was on a `SomethingElseViewController`. If you took that cast out, you wouldn't crash there. (And you'd probably run into trouble later.)

However, if what you really want to do is assert the validity of your storyboard and program, it might be better to be clear about that:

```
let someVC  = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("something")
assert(someVC is SomethingViewController)
// then do something non-SomethingViewController-specific with it
```